# Delaying the start of an animation on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

With the help of this forum I wrote some code to make an animation of a ball that goes into a basket.

My idea is that the user has to write the result of a mathematical operation within a time limit. If he gets it right, the ball goes into the basket.

The only problem is that I can't find out how to delay the start of the animation. My goal is to have a fixed canvas with a ball and a basket, and then at the end of the time limit I want the ball to start moving. I've tried to use a `sleep()` function that I got from the internet, but soon I learnt that it gave me more trouble than anything else. Here is a part of my code:

```
const tabx = 800, taby = 100; //backboard position
var canvas, ctx, i=0;

function init(z) { //z is the state of the function, at the start is 0 then goes to 1
    canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //backboard
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.rect(tabx, taby, 180, 100);
    ctx.stroke();

    //basket
    ctx.scale(1, 0.5);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(890, 320, 35, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.moveTo(855, 320);
    ctx.lineTo(865, 445);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.moveTo(925, 320);
    ctx.lineTo(915, 445);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.scale(1, 0.15);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(890, 2980, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); //setting transformation to default
    if (z == 0){
        start();
    }
}

function start() {
    var x1, y1, a, b, c, denom,x3,y3;

    //generating ball position
    x1 = (Math.random() * 500) + 100;
    y1 = (Math.random() * 200) + 300;

    canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //setting the end point of the parabola
    x3 = tabx + 90;
    y3 = taby + 90;

    //setting the medium point of the parabola
    x2 = (x1 + (x3+90))/ 2;
    y2 = ((y1 + (y3+220)) / 2) - 300;

    //calculating the equation of the parabola
    denom = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x3) * (x2 - x3);
    a = (x3 * (y2 - y1) + x2 * (y1 - y3) + x1 * (y3 - y2)) / denom;
    b = (x3 * x3 * (y1 - y2) + x2 * x2 * (y3 - y1) + x1 * x1 * (y2 - y3)) / denom;
    c = (x2 * x3 * (x2 - x3) * y1 + x3 * x1 * (x3 - x1) * y2 + x1 * x2 * (x1 - x2) * y3) / denom;

    drawball(a, b, c, x1, y1,x3);
}

function drawball(a, b, c, x1, y1, x3){
    var ris;
    canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //ball drawing
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x1, y1, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    if(i==1){
        sleep(3000);
        ris=genmat();
    }
    i++;
    if (x1 < x3) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
            init(1); //calling the init function to redraw everything
            y1 = a * (x1 * x1) + b * x1 + c;
            x1 += 10;

            //drawing the next ball
            drawpalla(a, b, c, x1, y1,x3)
        });
    }
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}
//function that generates the operation
function genmat(){
    var n1,n2,op,ris;
    n1=Math.trunc(Math.random()*10)
    n2=Math.trunc(Math.random()*10)
    op=Math.trunc((Math.random()*(4-1))+1)
    if(op==1){
        op="+";
        ris=n1+n2;
    }
    if(op==2){
        op="-";
        ris=n1-n2;
    }
    if(op==3){
        op="*";
        ris=n1*n2;
    }
    if(op==4){
        op="/";
        ris=n1/n2;
    }
   document.getElementById("mate").innerHTML=n1+op+n2;
   return ris;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using `setTimeout`?

Comment: ^ `setTimeout(() => { //animation code }, 3000)` will wait three seconds then execute the code inside settimeout.

Comment: But if I do that won't it wait 3 seconds for every frame of the animation?

Comment: So `drawball` is called in a tight loop?  Feels like we don't have quite enough code here to help

Comment: I've added the rest of the code